# Как в 1С:Предприятие 8.3 при повторной выгрузке данных из табличной части другого документа избежать очистки данных предыдущей выгрузки?

Tags: 1с

Имеется документ **ДоговораЗаказов**, в нем есть две табличные части: **ЗаказанныеТовары** и **Материалы**.
В табл. части **ЗаказанныеТовары** есть реквизиты **Наименование** *(Тип: СправочникСсылка.Товары)* и **Количество** *(Тип: Число)*. В справочнике **Товары** имеется своя табл. часть **Материалы**.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы пройтись по каждой из строк табл. части **ЗаказанныеТовары** и загружать в таблицу **Материалы** документа **ДоговораЗаказов** соответствующие данные из таблицы **Материалы** справочника **Товары**, попутно умножая материалы на количество таких товаров у данной строки данного наименования табл. части **ЗаказанныеТовары**.

По поводу того, как это все грамотно умножать еще не знаю, однако выгрузку сделал, вот код:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура Заполнить(Команда)
    Заполнение();
КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере
Процедура Заполнение()

    ТабОбх = Объект.ЗаказанныеТовары;
    Для Каждого стрТабл из ТабОбх Цикл

        массив = стрТабл.Наименование.Материалы.Выгрузить();
        Объект.Материалы.Загрузить(массив);

    КонецЦикла;

КонецПроцедуры
```

И все бы ничего, но только при каждом обходе строки из табл. части **ЗаказанныеТовары** происходит очищение табл. части **Материалы** документа **ДоговораЗаказов**. То есть происходит выгрузка, затем идет следующая строка, очищается табл. часть **Материалы** и происходит следующая выгрузка и так снова и снова.

Собственно вопрос: как сделать, чтобы не было этой очистки, чтобы табл. часть **Материалы** документа **ДоговораЗаказов** продолжала пополняться без очистки при следующей загрузке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный код очищает табличную часть Материалы в каждой итерации цикла и заполняет заново. Нужно на каждой итерации "ТабОбх" проходить еще и по табличной части "Материалы". Итог выглядит вот так

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура Заполнить(Команда)
    Заполнение();
КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере
Процедура Заполнение()

    ТабОбх = Объект.ЗаказанныеТовары;
    Для Каждого стрТабл из ТабОбх Цикл
        Для Каждого ст из стрТабл.Наименование.Материалы Цикл
          НС = Объект.Материалы.Добавить();
          ЗаполнитьЗначенияСвойств(НС, ст); // При условии что колонки в Объект.Материалы 
          // совпадают с Объект.ЗаказанныеТовары.Наименование.Материалы
          // Если нет - вручную прописываться соответствия
          // Например, так НС.Наименование = ст.НаименованиеПолное;
        КонецЦикла;
   КонецЦикла;

КонецПроцедуры
```

Comment: Воу, спасибо! И сразу пришло понимание как на количество умножить.
`&НаКлиенте
Процедура Заполнить(Команда)
    Объект.Материалы.Очистить();
    Заполнение();
КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере
Процедура Заполнение()

    ТабОбх = Объект.ЗаказанныеТовары;
    Для Каждого стрТабл из ТабОбх Цикл
        Для Каждого ст из стрТабл.Наименование.Материалы Цикл
            НС = Объект.Материалы.Добавить();
            НС.Наименование = ст.Наименование;
            НС.Количество = ст.Количество * стрТабл.Количество;
        КонецЦикла;
    КонецЦикла;

КонецПроцедуры`

Answer (score 0):

Воу, спасибо! И сразу пришло понимание как на количество умножить.

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура Заполнить(Команда)
    Объект.Материалы.Очистить();
    Заполнение();
КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере
Процедура Заполнение()

    ТабОбх = Объект.ЗаказанныеТовары;
    Для Каждого стрТабл из ТабОбх Цикл
        Для Каждого ст из стрТабл.Наименование.Материалы Цикл
            НС = Объект.Материалы.Добавить();
            НС.Наименование = ст.Наименование;
            НС.Количество = ст.Количество * стрТабл.Количество;
        КонецЦикла;
    КонецЦикла;

КонецПроцедуры
```